# make command is not detecting make file in windows10

Tags: makefile

I am using windows 10.
I have installed make.
I have created make file as "Makefile.mak" and kept in that directory.
But when i am use make command it is giving:
"make:*** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop." error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Makefile and .Mak File + CodeBlocks and VStudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1438643/makefile-and-mak-file-codeblocks-and-vstudio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make doesn't read `Makefile.mak` files.  It reads `Makefile` files.  If you want to use some other name, you need to tell make what the name is:

```
make -f Makefile.mak
```

See https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Makefile-Arguments.html

Comment: when i am running make command ,it is showing following error"make:*** no targets specified and no make file found. Stop.".Eventhough makefile is present in that directory.please help me to solve this issue

Comment: You marked this solution complete, but you also said you still had the problem in a comment.  Which is true?  If your makefile is named `makefile` or Makefile` (on Windows of course they are the same thing) with no extension in the same directory where you invoke `make` then it will be found.